# Sync Error after The Merge

Tags: the-merge, prysm

We are facing the problem of sync after the merge is completed. Gives multiple errors and one of them is "peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"

Comment: What execution client do you use with prysm?

Answer (score 1):

Seems related to connection to "bad" peers in early sync. I have done a resync after the Merge and got the same error a lot.